# Conforming Linked List to the Collection protocol

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures, linked-list

I'm looking at the Linked List implementation from [here](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/blob/master/Linked%20List/LinkedList.swift), and it shows how the class conforms to the [Collection protocol](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/blob/5d551049a02cccd00b046937750fd6d736065f76/Linked%20List/LinkedList.swift#L288):

```swift
extension LinkedList: Collection {
    
    public typealias Index = LinkedListIndex<T>

    public var startIndex: Index {
        get {
            return LinkedListIndex<T>(node: head, tag: 0)
        }
    }
    
    public var endIndex: Index {
        get {
            if let h = self.head {
                return LinkedListIndex<T>(node: h, tag: count)
            } else {
                return LinkedListIndex<T>(node: nil, tag: startIndex.tag)
            }
        }
    }
    
    public subscript(position: Index) -> T {
        get {
            return position.node!.value
        }
    }
    
    public func index(after idx: Index) -> Index {
        return LinkedListIndex<T>(node: idx.node?.next, tag: idx.tag + 1)
    }
}
```

In order to conform to the `Collection` protocol, the code provided three things: `startIndex`/`endIndex`, read-only subscript to get an element, and `index(after:)`.

And order to make this possible, the code also provided [LinkedListIndex](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/blob/5d551049a02cccd00b046937750fd6d736065f76/Linked%20List/LinkedList.swift#L329) which is a wrapper object of the linked list in question to make it conform to `Comparable`:

```swift
public struct LinkedListIndex<T>: Comparable {
    fileprivate let node: LinkedList<T>.LinkedListNode<T>?
    fileprivate let tag: Int
    
    public static func==<T>(lhs: LinkedListIndex<T>, rhs: LinkedListIndex<T>) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.tag == rhs.tag)
    }
    
    public static func< <T>(lhs: LinkedListIndex<T>, rhs: LinkedListIndex<T>) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.tag < rhs.tag)
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Why do the elements have to conform to `Comparable`? Unlike [firstIndex(of:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/2995095-firstindex)), which requires the elements to be `Equatable`, I can't seem to find anything on Apple documentation about needing to conform to `Comparable`, or even `Equatable`, for things like `startIndex`.
2. How do these tags refer to a specific node? I'm not quite understanding the association between this arbitrary property `tag` and index.

**Testing**

```swift
final class LinkListTest: XCTestCase {
    func test_linkedList() {
        let linkedList = LinkedList<Int>()
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: 100, by: 10) {
            linkedList.append(i)
        }
        
        let startIndex = linkedList.startIndex // startIndex has a tag of 0 because that's how it was instantiated
        let expectedStartIndex = LinkedListIndex<Int>(node: linkedList.head, tag: 0)
        XCTAssertEqual(startIndex, expectedStartIndex)
        
        let endIndex = linkedList.endIndex // endIndex also has a tag of the count because that's how it was instantiated
        let expectedEndIndex = LinkedListIndex<Int>(node: linkedList.last, tag: 10)
        XCTAssertEqual(endIndex, expectedEndIndex)
        
        let node = LinkedList.Node(value: 50)
        let testIndex = linkedList.index(after: LinkedListIndex<Int>(node: node, tag: 50))
        print("testIndex", testIndex) // LinkedListIndex<Int>(node: nil, tag: 51)
    }
}
```

There is no iteration going through every node and associating it with `LinkedListIndex` to say node C has a tag of 3, D has a tag of 4. How does `index(after:)` know which node comes after `LinkedListIndex<Int>(node: node, tag: 50)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you show:

1. It's not the linked list *elements* which are `Comparable`, but the *indices*. [`Collection`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/4f56488dfbe4029bbd56ddef45942a9f474ed65b/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L338) has no `Comparable` requirement on its elements, but does require that its indexes be comparable so that they can be reasonably ordered:

   ```
   public protocol Collection: Sequence {
     // FIXME: ideally this would be in MigrationSupport.swift, but it needs
     // to be on the protocol instead of as an extension
     @available(*, deprecated/*, obsoleted: 5.0*/, message: "all index distances are now of type Int")
     typealias IndexDistance = Int  

     // FIXME: Associated type inference requires this.
     override associatedtype Element

     /// A type that represents a position in the collection.
     ///
     /// Valid indices consist of the position of every element and a
     /// "past the end" position that's not valid for use as a subscript
     /// argument.
     associatedtype Index: Comparable

     // ...
   }
   ```

   This requirement on the indices makes it possible to iterate over the `Collection` one index at a time, and know where you are relative to `startIndex` and `endIndex`.

   Note too that the syntax

   ```
   public struct LinkedListIndex<T>: Comparable
   ```

   does *not* make `LinkedList` `Comparable` itself, and only declares that `LinkedListIndex` is `Comparable`. Note that it does not reference the original list itself, but holds on to a node for constant-time access back within `LinkedList` itself: but this implementation detail does not have to do with `Comparable` conformance, nor does it affect it.
2. It appears that `LinkedListIndex.tag` represents the index of the element in the list, like an array index: the first element (`startIndex`) has a tag of `0`, the second element has a tag of `1`, etc.; `endIndex` (the index once *past* the last element in the list) has an index of `count`

   You can use an index to iterate `tag` times through the list to access a specific element. This iteration isn't strictly necessary, though, because a `LinkedListIndex` *also* contains a pointer to the node it's supposed to refer to in the list, as a shortcut.

---

Update with additional question:

> How does index(after:) know which node comes after LinkedListIndex(node: node, tag: 50)?

This is achieved using two things:

1. Alongside the `tag`, `LinkedListIndex` values contain a pointer to the node that they reference in the original list:

   public struct LinkedListIndex: Comparable {
   fileprivate let node: LinkedList.LinkedListNode?
   fileprivate let tag: Int
   }

   This is set at the time that the index is *created* in:

   - `LinkedList.startIndex`
   - `LinkedList.endIndex`
   - `LinkedList.index(after:)`
2. The implementation of `LinkedList.index(after:)` uses this node reference in its implementation:

   ```
   public func index(after idx: Index) -> Index {
       return LinkedListIndex<T>(node: idx.node?.next, tag: idx.tag + 1)
   }
   ```

   The index which comes after `idx` is an index which:

   - Points to the node *after* `idx.node`, and
   - Has a tag which is one *past* `idx.tag`

There is no further association between a node and a tag:

- The `tag` appears to be used *exclusively* for `Comparable` conformance for indices, as a way to avoid having to compare nodes (e.g., `LinkedListIndex` *trusts* that if `idx1.tag < idx2.tag` then presumably `idx1.node` comes before `idx2.node` in the list, even if this is not the case!), while
- The `node` is the only thing really consulted when subscripting, and when producing new indices

Because the nodes and tags are only very loosely related in this way, this code isn't terribly robust against mismatches (e.g. if I edit the list while you hold on to an `index`, the index's `tag` may be out of date depending on the operation I perform!).

Comment: @Kevvv Updated my answer to (hopefully) clarify: there's nothing terribly special here, and you're right — the association between `node` and `tag` is very loose. Let me know if this elucidates or confuses more.